# Blender GLB format exporting issue

Tags: animation, export, file-format

I want to export my animation in glb format. In this animation there is an object that will appear and disappears at certain time. But when i export this animation, and view it online the object will stay appeared from the beginning.There is no appearing and disappear effect.
Can you guys please suggest any solution as it is urgent.

Comment: How is this animation realised? Apart from that, about the compatibility between softwares: [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures) (I know the question asks about materials, but this applies to all kinds of software-exclusive materials, modifiers, tools etc.)

Comment: glTF can only animate LocRotScale and shape key weights. So if you're animating eg hide_render it won't work.